# A cross-browser way to grow all table cells in a row to match the content of the largest one?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10, html-table, internet-explorer-11

I have an HTML table I'm using to display a timetable. The layout features I want to have in the end are:

1. If possible, have each table cell be the same size to make the table look regular. (Manually chosen to fit the most common contents.)
2. If the content is too long, make the cell taller to accommodate it. Also make all the other table cells in the same row taller to match the height. (Same for width and column, respectively, but that happens more rarely.)
3. The content has an inner border around it. (For the sake of simplicity. My actual stuff has other decorative styling that should **not** span the enclosing cell applied to it.)

**My question is**: is there a cross-browser way – preferrably not involving `X-UA-Compatible` – to get a layout with the above properties?

---

### Current code [(Codepen)](http://codepen.io/millimoose/pen/FgbKH):

#### HTML

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        Hello, world!
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### CSS

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;

  border: thin solid silver;
}

table td {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  padding: 1px;

  border: thin solid silver;
}

table td div {
  height: 100%;

  border: thin solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

(The `box-sizing: border-box;` on the `<td>` is really more OCD than anything, I just wanted the inside of the table cell have `60px` regardless of padding.)

---

### Rendering examples

This is how the above renders in three different browsers:

[image: Comparison of Chrome, IE11 and IE10]

- In **Chrome** (and Safari), everything renders as expected. There's a 1px padding around the inner `<div>`, and all the other `<div>`s in the row grow to fill the available height. So far so good.
- In **Internet Explorer 11**, the inner `<div>`s stick to the table cell. I.e. there's no padding, except for the right side of the cell, and even that not on the last cell in the row. (Huh?) However, the height does correctly expand.
- In **Internet Explorer 10**, the padding is applied correctly. Unfortunately, the long content of the third cell overflows the cell border, since the height is specified directly. Unsurprisingly, this is what's in my actual bugrep. (I'm using the emulation mode in IE's F12 Developer Tools to check this, but the rendering matches the screenshot I got in the bugrep.)

I tried using `min-height` instead of `height` on the `<td>` in the IE10 example. This solved the overflowing, but the inner `<div>` wouldn't expand:

[image: IE10 rendering using min-height]

So, I'm going for WebKit's / Blink's rendering, and I need it to work mainly on IE10, but hopefully IE11 as well. Bonus points for explaining what changed in IE11 to make my layout break in a way completely different to how it was broken in IE10.

---

### Additional samples of the IE11 issue

For completeness, I'm including screenshots of my actual app in Chrome and IE11:

[image: Full example – Chrome]

[image: Full example – IE11]

As you can see, the IE11 rendering breakage is more obvious than in the above example, to the point where table cells aren't vertically aligned. (If you look at the vertical line labelled `9:00` at the top.) I'm *guessing* this is because the `height: 100%` in the `<div>` means "take the `height` of the parent element", not "take the available vertical space", and the inside `padding` in the `<div>` is added to that. (Which makes a perverted sort of sense in the context of the standard box sizing model, but I guess the ship has sailed on that topic.)

Adding a `box-sizing: border-box;` on the inner `<div>` *almost, but not quite* fixes things, but the result looks outright glitchy and is probably a renderer bug:

[image: IE11, broken in new, intriguing ways]

Anyway, the IE11 breakage isn't my main issue here as much as IE10's content overflowing / cells not growing.

Comment: I'm stuck in XP + IE6 right now, so I can't test, but Firefox 25 renders your codepen like your IE10 screenshot. And I think that's quite reasonable, because you specifically said a `td` should be `60px` height.

Comment: @Passerby FF doesn't concern me for now, besides I already know what i have is somehow broken/incompatible. And I did mention that changing `height` to `min-height doesn't quite get me there - the `<div>` won't grow.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind not supporting < IE7, a simple fix would be to apply `display: inline-block` to the div.

[Example here.](http://cdpn.io/FgbKH)

Comment: This doesn't actually do anything, and you linked to my pen - it's not really an example of what you're proposing. (That might have been a mistake - it's a better idea to fork it yourself to make changes since I could've overwritten your edits to mine.) Doing that gives me [this rendering](https://www.dropbox.com/s/prwzf8g1r8w1f5o/Screenshot%202013-11-13%2003.46.35.png) under IE10 mode. ([Forked pen](http://codepen.io/millimoose/pen/hEkiI) with just `display: inline-block;` added.)